# How can I inject multiple services into one controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an EmailAccountsController and I need to inject 'Hosting' and 'EmailAccount' services into it. Here is my code:

```
hostingsModule.controller('EmailAccountsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Hosting', 'EmailAccount', function ($scope, Hosting, EmailAccount) {
    var hostingId = 1
    $scope.hosting = Hosting.find(hostingId);
    $scope.emailAccounts = EmailAccount.all(hostingId)
}]);
```

The error message is `TypeError: Cannot call method 'all' of undefined`

When I inject only one service into the same controller, everything works. Is there a way how to inject multiple services into one controller?

EDIT: I've tried to put all the relevant code into one file. It' looks like this:

```
hostingsModule.factory('Hosting', ['$http', function($http) {
    var Hosting = function(data) {
        angular.extend(this, data);
    };

    Hosting.all = function() {      
        return $http.get('<%= api_url %>/hostings.json').then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };

    Hosting.find = function(id) {
        return $http.get('<%= api_url %>/hostings/' + id + '.json').then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }

    return Hosting; 
}]);

hostingsModule.factory('EmailAccount', ['$http', function($http) {
    var EmailAccount = function(data) {
        angular.extend(this, data);
    };

    EmailAccount.all = function(hostingId) {        
        return $http.get('<%= api_url %>/hostings/' + hostingId + '/email-accounts.json').then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };

    EmailAccount.find = function(id) {
        return $http.get('<%= api_url %>/hostings/' + id + '.json').then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
}]);

hostingsModule.controller('EmailAccountsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Hosting', 'EmailAccount',     function($scope, Hosting, EmailAccount) {
    var hostingId = 1;

    $scope.hosting = Hosting.find(hostingId);
    $scope.emailAccounts = EmailAccount.all(hostingId)

    console.log($scope.hosting);
    console.log($scope.emailAccounts);
}]);
```

Comment: Your example should work. The issue is most likely somewhere else, are you sure you have a service called `EmailAccount` and if you do, is the module it's in required correctly?

Comment: Could you please post your `EmailAccount` service?. Also console.log() your EmailAccount service

Comment: Have you tried to call any other methods of EmailAccount? Or any methods of Hosting?

Comment: Your service should be defined over the same module `hostingsModule`

Comment: @BrettDeWoody: other methods of EmailAccount are not working. Methods of Hosting are.

Comment: @dcodesmith please see my edit for EmailAccount service code. When I try to log EmailAccount, I get undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope issue. You need to return `EmailAccount` since it is initialized inside the closure. 
You need to add `return EmailAccount;` like what you did for `Hosting`.

Or try this code:

```
hostingsModule.factory('EmailAccount', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var service = {
        all: function (hostingId) {
            return $http.get('<%= api_url %>/hostings/' + hostingId + '/email-accounts.json').then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        },

        find: function (id) {
            return $http.get('<%= api_url %>/hostings/' + id + '.json').then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot! I've just spend more than two hours on this one. Thank you very much!